# Nginx with RTMP server fail to start on boot on Raspberry Pi

Tags: boot, server

I installed Nginx with RTMP server usnig the infos available on [this tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=89605) on Raspberry Pi.

It is impossible for me to find out why Nginx does not start on boot. I have tried most of the available solutions on the internet, looking at the /etc/init.d/nginx script, using update-rc to update it, stopping and restarting the service for the update to take effect, but could not get it working. The most standard way of doing was that one:

> sudo bash -c "echo 'sudo /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx' >
>   /etc/init.d/nginx"; sudo chmod 775 /etc/init.d/nginx; sudo
>   /usr/sbin/update-rc.d -f nginx defaults

and if I type

```
service nginx start ; ps -ef | grep nginx
Job for nginx.service failed. See 'systemctl status nginx.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for d                                                                                                etails.
root      1434  1084  0 17:23 pts/0    00:00:00 grep nginx
root@rpi:/home/pi# systemctl status nginx.service -l
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-06-10 17:23:36 UTC; 6min ago
  Process: 1429 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Jun 10 17:23:36 rpi systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=203
Jun 10 17:23:36 rpi systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Jun 10 17:23:36 rpi systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the issue by modifying the config of Nginx sudo nano (`/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`) by adding:

> pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

Reload the daemon loader:

> systemctl daemon-reload

And restart the Raspberry Pi:

> reboot

The server should now boot at startup.